# Serverless Deploy returns bucket already exists

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a Serverless function for uploading an image to a pre-existing bucket that works offline, but when I try and deploy I either get...

`An error occurred: ImageUploadBucket - MYUNIQUEBUCKET already exists.`or  `An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - imageupload-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole already exists.` even though I am deploying my function to `eu-west-1.`

Here is my YML...

```
...  
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::MYUNIQUEBUCKET/*"
  environment:
        region: eu-west-2
        imageUploadBucket: ${self:custom.imageUploadBucket}

custom:
    region: eu-west-2
    bucketName: MYUNIQUEBUCKET
    imageUploadBucket: MYUNIQUEBUCKET
    serverless-offline:
        httpPort: 3001

plugins:
    - serverless-offline

functions:
  newImageUpload:
        handler: ImageUpload.requestUploadURL
        events:
            - http:
                path: image-upload
                method: POST
                cors: true
            - s3:
                bucket: MYUNIQUEBUCKET
                event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
                existing: true

resources:
  Resources:
    ImageUploadBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: MYUNIQUEBUCKET
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        CorsConfiguration:
        ...
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Buckets and IAM roles and permissions are global, that is why they exist.

S3 Bucket names are also unique and global across all AWS accounts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I know this, but I am not sure why it is not working to use the existing bucket when I have existing: true in the code (although not sure in the right place). Also I keep deleting the IAM role but even though I am selecting EU-West-1 it still keeps creating a US-East-1 role

Comment: There is no such thing as a US-east-1 role, the role would be visible in every region. That being said I see this https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6771